# Keeping mouse cursor over the handle when mouse moves

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've built a simple table column resizer here:

http://jsfiddle.net/44k6c/

I can't use a plugin for this but I need to mimic functionality in this plugin:

http://quocity.com/colresizable/

I've managed to et the cols resizing well but my cursor is allowed to move away from the handle (the grey box in the th). I need to somehow constrain the cursor so it stays over the handle as the mouse is moved. I've looked in to the source code of the plugin above but it hasn't shed any light on how to achieve this.

My js code is a work in progress and is fairly rough at the moment:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

                var th,
                    previousColIndex,
                    nextColIndex,
                    previousColWidth,
                    nextColWidth,
                    thWidth,
                    currentXPos;

                $('.resize').mousedown(function(e) {
                     currentXPos = e.pageX; 
                     th = $(this).parent();
                     nextColIndex = th.index() + 1;
                     nextColWidth = $('table tr th').eq(nextColIndex).width();
                     thWidth = th.width();
                     $(document).bind('mousemove',function(e){
                         if(e.pageX < currentXPos) {
                            thWidth = thWidth - 1;
                            nextColWidth = nextColWidth + 1;
                            $('table tr td').eq(th.index()).css({'width': thWidth + 'px'});
                            th.css({'width':thWidth + 'px' });
                            $('table tr td,table tr th').eq(nextColIndex).css({'width': nextColWidth  + 'px'});
                            currentXPos = e.pageX; 
                         } else {
                            thWidth = thWidth + 1;
                            nextColWidth = nextColWidth - 1;
                            $('table tr td').eq(th.index()).css({'width': thWidth + 'px'});
                            th.css({'width':thWidth + 'px' });
                            $('table tr td,table tr th').eq(nextColIndex).css({'width': nextColWidth  + 'px'});
                            currentXPos = e.pageX; 
                         }


                     })
                }).mouseup(function(){


$(document).unbind('mousemove');


})

    $(document).mouseup(function() {
    $(document).unbind('mousemove');

 })
 })
```

Comment: I don't think you and also don't think you should constrain the cursor. The cursor is built into the OS. Maybe it is possible, but I still don't think it's good to try to rewrite basic functionality like that.

Comment: Well i think seing it move is a lot better, only problem is that the mouse moves the opposite way. Don't know how to block it though, but that would be much less intuitive imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44k6c/4/)** resolve the problem?

You probably had an issue in this lines:

```
thWidth = thWidth - 1;
nextColWidth = nextColWidth + 1;
```

it probably should be:

```
thWidth = thWidth - currentXPos + e.pageX;
nextColWidth = nextColWidth + currentXPos - e.pageX;
```

**EDIT:**
Bad link. Use this one: http://jsfiddle.net/44k6c/4/